# Relation between density and viscosity

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Viscosity is resistance to the motion of fluid layers sliding over one another. Density is a measure of forces of attraction between atoms or molecules of same species. Is there any relation between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mercury is very dense but pours easily
Honey is lighter but is very viscous - (changes with temperature though)

Density and viscosity are two different characteristics of a fluid.

Viscosity has the units Poise for dynamic viscosity and Stokes for kinematic viscosity.

Comment: Stokes & Poise are old metric names from the gram-centimetre-second system, that was used by laboratories. In the SI system, there are no special names for the units for [viscosity] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) & [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density). The SI units for viscosity are Pa.s, or (N.s)/m2 or kg/(s.m), while the SI unit for density is kg/m3

Comment: Says here that it is centipoise (cP) and centistokes (cSt) ...http://www.rheosense.com/basics/viscosity-units   obviously depends on the source as it varies by country...